# How can I draw line diagrams on a tty?

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, terminal, 2d

I'm writing a command line (non-graphical) Linux program in C++, and in some places I need it to draw a chart or plot a function right into the terminal.

Looking at some programs like ntsysv, mc, alsa etc., I believe it's possible but I was wondering how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seconding the ncurses recommendation, there also exists a library called [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca), a graphics library that outputs ASCII text instead of pixels. If you want to create this graphs with other software and then push their output to the terminal you could consider using libcaca with ncurses.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) and to do some [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

Answer (score 2):

Things like alsamixer use ncurses. http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

This will let you make diagrams and whatnot directly in the terminal.

Comment: thank U too... I'm a beginner here and I'm not allowed to vote up yet :(

Answer (score 0):

try with the old borland library for turbo c conio.h

Comment: Which Linux includes that?  I've never seen it provided on Debian or Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that's not needed anymore but maybe that's helping somebody

```
void drawfunc(int ymin, int ymax, int xmin, int xmax, float h){
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
double func;

for(y = ymax; y >= ymin; y--)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(x = xmin; x <= xmax; x++)
    {
        func = cos(x);
        
        if(x == 0)
        {
            printf("|");
        }
        
        if(func > (y - 1) * h && func < y * h)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        else if(y == 0)
        {
            if(x >= xmin || x <= xmax)
            {
                printf("-");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}
printf("\n\n");}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how it answers the question.